# Can not tap on presented ViewController on TopViewController XCode 8.1, iphone6s/6s+/7/7+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, xcode8

I want present a ViewController on top application so I use the codes below

```
let nextStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
let menu = nextStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuView") as! MenuPanelViewController

UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.getTopViewController().modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen

UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.getTopViewController().presentViewController(menu, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Everything fine when I use xCode 7, when I update xCode to 8.1, on iPhone 6s/6s+/7/7+ I cannot use tapRecognizer.

I think my problem related 3D Touch on these above devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your getTopViewontroller() returns correctly.

This is the method I am using to find the top most presented view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController() -> UIViewController {
        return UIApplication.topViewController(base: nil)
    }
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController {
        var baseView = base
        if baseView == nil {
            baseView = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController
        }
        if let vc = baseView?.presentedViewController {
            return UIApplication.topViewController(base: vc)
        } else {
            return baseView!
        }
    }
}
```